# Is there a way to get location in C# other than GeoCoordinate Watcher?

Tags: c#, arcgis-runtime, esri-maps

I am trying to implement a current location method in my app for ESRI ArcGIS it requires getting current latitude and longitude so i used geo coordinate watcher for it unfortunately i got system.device doesn't exist , i tried to rectify it but did not work also i know in unity we can use something like input.location.lastData.longitude and so on can we do the same thing here? I need an alternative if possible

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to find any answer but there is a solution that closely matches my requirements basically i only needed latitude and longitude in ArcGIS maps so i could initialize the buffer at the point but i have taken care of it with this tutorial.

[Device Location Display in ArcGIS](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/device-location/tutorials/display-device-location/)